# Word Document Cannot find module or it's corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting this error trying to import this file from `src/assets/documents` folder.

[image]

I am working on a React Project with Typescript. I am trying to import the file and feed it's value in an anchor tag so it can be downloaded.

When I'm importing images from `src/assets/images`, this problem is not existing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: How have you configured Webpack to handle `.doc` files?

Comment: @Quentin i think we don't have a webpack configuration in our project currently.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Since you are using TypeScript you will need to define the type of the data you are importing.

The solution is fairly simple you need to create a proxy file which will map the types.

Usually the of the file ends with **.d.ts**

In Vue for example the convention is shims-vue.d.ts

Click [here][1] to see an example

The content of the fie should be:

```
declare module '*.doc' {
    
      import nameOfDoc from src/assets/documents (should be your path to the doc)
      export default nameOfDoc
    }
```